# What are .dockerenv and .dockerinit?

Tags: docker

What are the `.dockerenv` and `.dockerinit` files in the root of my container's filesystem?  How are they used? Is there any documentation on these files?

```
root@18ceee4f9041:/# ls -al /
total 72
drwxr-xr-x.  21 root root 4096 Jan  4 20:45 .
drwxr-xr-x.  21 root root 4096 Jan  4 20:45 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root    0 Jan  4 20:45 .dockerenv
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root    0 Jan  4 20:45 .dockerinit
```

Other people have asked similar questions, but I can find no answers:

- [.dockerinit / .dockerenv](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-dev/fmh-_594pnM) (9/12/2015)

I'm asking because I'm working on [a bug in my docker-executing tool called scuba](https://github.com/JonathonReinhart/scuba/issues/11). You can pass `--user` to `docker run` to set the UID of the process in a container, but it has no entry in /etc/passwd, so I was investigating options for creating the user during container startup.

(Cross-posted [at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601553/what-are-dockerenv-and-dockerinit), where it may be closed.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AFAIK there is no official documentation about them.

Those files where only used by the old and [deprecated LXC execution driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/misc/deprecated/#lxc-built-in-exec-driver). They were hacks required by docker when using LXC to run the containers.

The `.dockerinit` was a sort of [init process](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init). It was the binary run by the [`lxc-attach`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lxc-attach) command called when starting a container. It was the responsible to setup the environment, the user and the working directory and then run your entrypoint/cmd.

The `.dockerenv` contained the environment variables defined inside the container. They were used to setup the environment variables properly after the lxc-attach. This file [was read by the `.dockerinit` process](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/v1.9.1/daemon/execdriver/lxc/init.go#L107-L134).

The new [libcontainer](https://github.com/docker/libcontainer)/[runc](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc) driver ([the driver enabled by default](https://blog.docker.com/2014/03/docker-0-9-introducing-execution-drivers-and-libcontainer/)) does not use these files. You will find them empty in your containers. In fact, [the LXC support has been recently removed from the docker development branch](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/3b5fac462d21ca164b3778647420016315289034).

So maybe these files will eventually disappear in the future, although currently are widely used by applications to detect the presence of docker.

Comment: A small inaccuracy: According to the source code, they’re mount points, specified in Docker’s core, not specific to the LXC driver.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Those files are part of a list of mount points created as empty files in the Docker core when creating the root FS. But those two specific files/mountpoints are only used by LXC.

Comment: Thank you for this. Could you please see my edit regarding "scuba"?  Also, could you elaborate on *"It was the responsible to setup... the user"* ? This is relevant to my issue.

Comment: It sets the username passed to the `-u` argument. You can read the implementation [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/v1.9.1/daemon/execdriver/lxc/driver.go#L493-L530).

Comment: Regarding the problem with your scuba project, see some solutions to the user id problem here: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7198

Comment: Thanks a lot @zuazo. I ended up working around the issue by creating a user in the container which matches the uid of the invoking user on the host.  See [JonathonReinhart/scuba#11](https://github.com/JonathonReinhart/scuba/issues/11).

Comment: It comes to 2020 and `/.dockerenv` still exists in every docker container.

Comment: @ttimasdf And that's good... I just found out that checking `/proc/1/cgroup` doesn't work for cgroups V2, and I need a way to know if I'm being run inside docker or not, these empty files are a very simple thing to solve that requirement.

Answer (score 10):

In order to find out, whether their code is running inside a docker environment, it was popular to test for the existence of either the `/.dockerinit` or the `/.dockerenv` file.

Since the dockerinit file [has been removed](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18355) in newer versions, the best idea should now be to check the existence of the dockerenv file.

- Quoting [another source](https://github.com/minio/minio/pull/1330):

  > I'm not sure how official `/.dockerenv` is -- it's pretty much undocumented, but [docker/libnetwork#815](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/pull/815) seems to imply that it'll be longer-lived

A sample implementation of such a check from our code:

```
if ! [ -f /.dockerenv ] ; then
  echo "Not running inside docker, exiting to avoid data damage." >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: According to another answer here, testing for `.dockerenv` is not reliable either. Isn't there a more solid way to test for whether code is inside docker?

Comment: If you rely on that, why not add your own layer to put it there, in case your base image lacks it?